# How to call periodically a function in Python turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have to code a game with turtle library.
In the rules, there is an object that fells every X milliseconds until a certain condition is reached.

If I use sleep(), the screen does not respond anymore to the keyboard events. Is there any way to periodically call a function "asynchronously" ?
Many thanks !

Comment: You should read the documentation of the turtle graphics module. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#animation-control and https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#using-screen-events

Comment: Why downvote ? Can you explain why I should create a delay ? It will more not responds.

Sorry for my bad english. I read your link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python turtle provides a *one-shot*:

```
screen.ontimer(my_function, milliseconds)
```

which you can turn into an *every X milliseconds* timer event:

```
def my_function():
    pass  # do whatever

    if still_needed:  # start again in the future if still needed
        screen.ontimer(my_function, 100)  # repeat every 0.1 second
```

Comment: I did it like that too but unfortunately, it did not respond to events but I just found my mistake.

I was doing :
screen.onkey(x, "Down")
screen.onkeyrelease(y, "Down")

But the first event wasn't triggered

I changed it to "onkeypress"